# ASP.NET Cache unique

Tags: asp.net

Is HttpRuntime Cache unique for each user in ASP.NET as well as the Sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [HttpRuntime Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) is stored on the server side, and is valid application-wide.

Comment: Correct, but not because it's stored on the server side. Session data is also stored on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The cache isn't unique for each user as @Dan Dumitru said but you could use it in a fake unique way by specifying a unique string as part of the key for the cached data (username or user id from a table etc)...This does of course mean lots of things would be cached depending on usage...it would then be subject to all the usual cache scenarios

```
Function GetDataFromCache() As Object

    Return Cache.Item(String.Concat(My.User.Name, "SomeDataThatIsCachedForEachUser"))

End Function
```

Comment: There is no point in manually calling `String.Concat`.  Use the `+` operator.